# Why isn't my html page reading my .css styles sheet?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am implementing `bootstrap 5` in my `html` page. The code is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="/main_styles.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

When I run the page in my server, it doesn't read any styles from my `main_styles.css` sheet. Why?

Comment: Depends how routing is set up. Open up `developer tools` on your browser and it will tell you if it can't load it for whatever reason (possibly a 404)

Comment: Nope, there's nothing in the console

Comment: What is your server's root folder, and what is the path to the stylesheet ?

Comment: Is that server up anywhere so I can take a look ?

Comment: The stylesheet is in the root folder only. And no, I am running it in the localhost server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `href` for `link` tags, not `src`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main_styles.css">
```

That should work

Comment: God damn it!! I am so stupid XD

Comment: Don't worry, I can't believe we didn't notice it until now either, small things...